# Null data when i get Accent from db

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys when i want to return json data like this `éééééé` it return `null` not the value
code :

```
<?php

$aColumns = array(
'id',
'add_date',
'user',
'pass', 
'statut',
'commentaire'

);

$sIndexColumn = "id";
$sTable = "contet";
$gaSql['user'] = "root";
$gaSql['password'] = "";
$gaSql['db'] = "test";
$gaSql['server'] = "localhost";


// DATABASE CONNECTION
function dbinit(&$gaSql) {
    // ERROR HANDLING
    function fatal_error($sErrorMessage = '') {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error');
        die($sErrorMessage);
    }

    // MYSQL CONNECT
    if ( !$gaSql['link'] = @mysql_connect($gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']) ) {
        fatal_error('Could not open connection to server');
    }

    // MYSQL DATABASE SELECT
    if ( !mysql_select_db($gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link']) ) {
        fatal_error('Could not select database');
    }
}

// AJAX EDIT FROM JQUERY
if ( isset($_GET['edit']) && 0 < intval($_GET['edit']) ) {
    dbinit($gaSql);

    // SAVE DATA
    if ( isset($_POST) ) {
        $p = $_POST;
        foreach ( $p as &$val ) $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
        if ( !empty($p['statut']) || !empty($p['commentaire'])  )
            @mysql_query(" UPDATE $sTable SET statut = '" . $p['statut'] . "', commentaire = '" . $p['commentaire'] ."' WHERE id = " . intval($_GET['edit']));
    }

    // GET DATA
    $query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM $sTable WHERE $sIndexColumn = " . intval($_GET['edit']), $gaSql['link']);
    die (json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($query)));
}

// AJAX ADD FROM JQUERY
if ( isset($_GET['add']) && isset($_POST) ) {
    dbinit($gaSql);

    $p = $_POST;
    foreach ( $p as &$val ) $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
    if ( !empty($p['statut']) || !empty($p['commentaire']) ) {
        @mysql_query(" INSERT INTO $sTable (statut, commentaire) VALUES ('" . $p['statut'] . "', '" . $p['commentaire'] . "')");
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        $query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM $sTable WHERE $sIndexColumn = " . $id, $gaSql['link']);
        die (json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($query)));
    }
}

// AJAX REMOVE FROM JQUERY
if ( isset($_GET['remove']) && 0 < intval($_GET['remove']) ) {
    dbinit($gaSql);

    // REMOVE DATA
    @mysql_query(" DELETE FROM $sTable WHERE id = " . intval($_GET['remove']));
}


// AJAX FROM JQUERY
if ( isset($_GET['ajax']) ) {
    dbinit($gaSql);

    // QUERY LIMIT
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['iDisplayStart']) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' ) {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT " . intval($_GET['iDisplayStart']) . ", " . intval($_GET['iDisplayLength']);
    }

    // QUERY ORDER
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['iSortCol_0']) ) {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY ";
        for ( $i = 0; $i < intval($_GET['iSortingCols']); $i++ ) {
            if ( $_GET['bSortable_' . intval($_GET['iSortCol_' . $i])] == "true" ) {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[intval($_GET['iSortCol_' . $i])] . " " . ( $_GET['sSortDir_' . $i] === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc' ) . ", ";
            }
        }
        $sOrder = substr_replace($sOrder, "", -2);
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" ) $sOrder = "";
    }

    // QUERY SEARCH
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" ) {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++ ) {
            if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_' . $i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_' . $i] == "true" ) {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch']) . "%' OR ";
            }
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace($sWhere, "", -3);
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    // BUILD QUERY
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++ ) {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_' . $i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_' . $i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_' . $i] != '' ) {
            if ( $sWhere == "" ) $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            else $sWhere .= " AND ";
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_' . $i]) . "%' ";
        }
    }

    // FETCH
    $sQuery = " SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS " . str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns)) . " FROM $sTable $sWhere $sOrder $sLimit ";
    $rResult = mysql_query($sQuery, $gaSql['link']) or fatal_error('MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno());
    $sQuery = " SELECT FOUND_ROWS() ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query($sQuery, $gaSql['link']) or fatal_error('MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno());
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];
    $sQuery = " SELECT COUNT(" . $sIndexColumn . ") FROM $sTable ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query($sQuery, $gaSql['link']) or fatal_error('MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno());
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];
    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array($rResult) ) {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count($aColumns); $i++ ) {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" ) $row[] = ( $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] == "0" ) ? '-' : $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' ) $row[] = $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = array_merge($row, array('<a data-id="row-' . $row[0] . '" href="javascript:editRow(' . $row[0] . ');" class="btn btn-md btn-success">edit</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:removeRow(' . $row[0] . ');" class="btn btn-default btn-md" style="background-color: #c83a2a;border-color: #b33426; color: #ffffff;">remove</a>'));
    }

    // RETURN IN JSON
    die(json_encode($output));
}

?>
```

this is what json return `"deva","rudiansyah","09\/07\/1932",null` when i had `éééé` or somthing like that . I add header in the code doesn't work and i add meta in html same problem.

If somthing doesn't clear I will add it.

Comment: you should lose `mysql_` functions, now deprecated for good reasons, and adopt a prepared statements approach.  Also you should definitely lose the `@`. That being said, read the docs on json_encode, some options apply (utf8) . Start by reading **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279)**.

Comment: Also, that is a lot of code to plough through. Help us help you by providing a   a **[minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: put this before your select query  `mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')`

Comment: You mean like that `$query = mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'," SELECT * FROM $sTable WHERE $sIndexColumn = " . $id, $gaSql['link']);` doesn't work for me same problem

Comment: I know that problem about `ut8` but i don"t where i should put it in my code that's why i put all code